# How to properly remove an attachment from an email using Aspose.Email

Tags: c#, aspose

In my application users can upload emails to a file server, these emails should then be stripped of their attachments and converted into a PDF to be saved individually. But I'm having problems correctly removing the attachments from the email.
When I'm converting an email and saving it with its attachments it works perfectly, but when I remove the attachments first and then save it, it somehow corrupts the generated PDF file making it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmVAs.png) (this is just one of 4 pages generated from a 4 line email). Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

This is my code to remove the attachments from the email:

```cs
public static List<(string FileName, Stream Content)> GetEmailAndAttachmentsFromEmail(Stream emailContent)
{
    var email = MailMessage.Load(emailContent);
    var retval = new List<(string, Stream)>
    {
        ($"{email.Subject}.msg", emailContent)
    };

    var attachmentsToRemove = new List<Attachment>();
    foreach (var attachment in email.Attachments)
    {
        retval.Add((attachment.Name, attachment.ContentStream));
        attachmentsToRemove.Add(attachment);
    }

    foreach (var attachment in attachmentsToRemove)
    {
        email.Attachments.Remove(attachment);
    }

    return retval;
}
```

I've already tried multiple permutations of this code, but none worked.
Also, I'm following the [official Aspose documentation](https://docs.aspose.com/display/emailnet/Working+with+Attachments+and+Embedded+Objects) on this subject and I don't see what I'm doing differently/ wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I did something funky with my streams and I had to save my email without the attachments before returning it, here is my revised code:

```cs
public static List<(string FileName, Stream Content)> GetEmailAndAttachmentsFromEmail(Stream emailContent)
{
    var email = MailMessage.Load(emailContent);
    // I removed the prepending of the email here and moved it to the end
    var retval = new List<(string, Stream)>();

    var attachmentsToRemove = new List<Attachment>();
    foreach (var attachment in email.Attachments)
    {
        retval.Add((attachment.Name, attachment.ContentStream));
        attachmentsToRemove.Add(attachment);
    }

    foreach (var attachment in attachmentsToRemove)
    {
        email.Attachments.Remove(attachment);
    }

    // This part is new
    var newEmailContent = new MemoryStream();
    email.Save(newEmailContent);
    newEmailContent.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    retval = retval.Prepend(($"{email.Subject}.msg", newEmailContent)).ToList();

    return retval;
}
```

It now works like a charm